# プロジェクトの外からTypeScriptで実装されたVueコンポーネントをインポートする時にエラーTS2345 を予防する

Tags: node.js, vue.js, typescript

プロジェクト・ディレクトリの外から[vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator)で実装されたVueコンポーネントをインポートしてみて、TypeScriptコンパイルの時に下記のエラーが出ました：

```js
TS2345: Argument of type '{ template: string; components: { SimpleCheckbox: typeof SimpleCheckbox; }; }' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'VueClass<Vue>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'template' does not exist in type 
'VueClass<Vue>'.
```

WebStromは此のエラーに就いて警告を出しません、エラーが出ているのはWebpackを実行する時だけです（TypeScriptのローダーは[ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)です）。

エラーが起きている所は：

```js
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import template from './SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.pug';
import SimpleCheckbox from './../../../../ui-kit-libary-in-development/UiComponents/Checkboxes/MaterialDesign/SimpleCheckbox.vue';

// ここです！
@Component({ template, components: { SimpleCheckbox } }) 
export default class SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly text!: string;
}
```

`ui-kit-libary-in-development`という名前からわかる通り、これは開発中のライブラリで未だ`npm`依存性ではないので、`node_modules`の中にはありません。

これはTypeScriptだけのエラーで、`ts-loader`により起きるものの、Webpackでコンパイル・ビルドされたアプリのJavaScriptは正常に動いています（ブラウザーのコンソールにエラーは一切ありません）。

下記の対策を取れば、エラーが無くなります：

- `SimpleCheckbox.vue`を`SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts`と同じディレクトリに移動し`import SimpleCheckbox from './SimpleCheckbox.vue';`の様にインポートします。
- `@Component({ template, components: { SimpleCheckbox } })`から`SimpleCheckbox` を取り除き、`@Component({ template, components: {} })`だけ残します。 (勿論、 `SimpleCheckbox`はレンダリングされなくなりますが、実験の為に確認するべきの事でした)
- `ui-kit-libary-in-development`を主要プロジェクトの`node_modules`に移動した上で、`ui-kit-libary-in-development`からこれの`node_modules`を取り除きます（取り除かなければ、エラーが変わらなく、無くなりません。従って、`npm link`は問題解決に成りません）

残念ながら、このエラーの再現は出来ませんでした。どういう訳か、下記のコードではエラーが再現しません:

**MainProject/src/Application.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
  PageOne
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import PageOne from './PageComponents/PageOne'

  @Component({ components: { PageOne }})
  export default class Application extends Vue {
    private created(): void {
      console.log('Done.');
    }
  }
</script>
```

**MainProject/src/PageComponents/PageOne.ts**

```js
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import template from './PageOne.pug';
import Button from './../../../UiKitLibraryStillInDevelopment/UiComponents/Buttons/Button.vue';


@Component({ template, components: { Button } })
export default class SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel extends Vue {}
```

**MainProject/src/PageComponents/PageOne.pug**

```
.RootElement
  Button(:text="'Click me'")
```

**ui-kit-libary-in-development/UiComponents/Buttons/Button.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
  button {{ text }}
</template>


<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component
  export default class SimpleCheckbox extends Vue {
    @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly text!: string;

    private created(): void {
      console.log('OK!');
      console.log(this.$props);
    }
  }
</script>
```

エラーの解決の助言の中に見つけたのは[GitHubのissue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/123)からのこのコメントだけです:

> 私が知っている限り、正常な動きの為に外部のコンポネントに`.d.ts`が必要。
>   Side components should add .d.ts for it to work AFAIK.
>
> [Nick Messing](https://github.com/nickmessing)

でも、このコメントによって、私の中に新たな質問が生まれました:

- `.d.ts`を作らなければならないのは、どこですか？主要なプロジェクトですか、依存性ですか？ 主要なプロジェクトだとしたら、何故`vuetify`の様なライブラリからコンポーネントが無事にインポートされますか? あちらで`.d.ts`がありますから!
- どうやって`vue-property-decorator`を使う場合の`.d.ts`を書けば良いですか?一例・チュートリアル等ありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

原因は`ts-loader`にある。タイプティックを[fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin)に任せれば、問題解決。